# Search bar not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, search, frontend

I've created a simply Search bar using JQuery only problem is that it hides everything, even when I've entered the correct name and for some reason when I delete the input it doesn't return the hidden items.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var uInput = $("#search").val();
    var id = $(".gali").attr("id");
    if (uInput != id){
        $(".gali").hide();
    } else {
        $(".gali").show();
    }
});

    <div id="container">
        <div id="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search">
        </div>

        <ul id="pList">
            <li class="gali">
                <img src="phot/plum01.jpg" class="pimg">
            </li>
            <li class="gali">
                <img src="phot/plum02.jpg" class="pimg">
            </li>
            <li class="gali" id="flowers">
                <img src="phot/plum03.jpg" class="pimg">
            </li>
            <li class="gali">
                <img src="phot/plum04.jpg" class="pimg">
            </li>
            <li class="gali" id="flowers">
                <img src="phot/plum05.jpg" class="pimg">
            </li>
            <li class="gali" id="flowers">
                <img src="phot/plum06.jpg" class="pimg">
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Please, provide us the html code. It would be very useful if you build a plunker or something like that. https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: Hi Doc, welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see the rest of your code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: For something this simplistic, plnkr, jsFiddle, codepen, etc, are hardly necessary. Just use the in-line web snippet tool.

Comment: your code works just fine.

Comment: You mention that "It hides everything" - do you mean all occurrences of the class `.gali`? If so, what `id` are you hoping to get by doing `$(".gali").attr("id");` ?

Comment: @RaphaelParreira Don't recommend remote sites when they can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have multiple`class="gali"`elements on your page.

`$('.gali').hide()`and`$('.gali').show()`will hide or show all such elements.

To avoid this you can implement a loop and check every`class="gali"`element individually:

```
$('.gali').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('id') == uInput.val()) {
        $this.show();
    } else {
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

EDIT: Or, as Santi suggests below, there is a better solution: hide all`class="gali"`elements, and then show the one with the id in question.

```
$(".gali").hide();
$("#"+id).show();
```

With this code, if your id does not exist, it simply will not be shown.

Comment: If this is in fact what OP is trying to do - hide an element of class `.gali`, based on ID, a loop is hardly necessary.

Comment: ^ The exact solution I had in mind. Though I'm still a bit curious as to what `id` OP is attempting to fetch by using `$(".gali").attr("id")`.

Comment: @Santi: True story.  Your solution is better.  Updating above.